# VUEX - Many mapActions with same action name on the same page

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have several differents files for a lot of modules.
Some of the share the same action name

There is some page that use 2 or more mapActions for different modules
On my page is something like this:

```js
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
        documents: ['setDocumentImage'],
        documentAddress: ['setDocumentImage'],
        selfie: ['setDocumentImage']
    }),
}
```

All my modules have a action `setDocumentImage`
But the problem is that i have to invoke them like: `this.setDocumentImage(file)`

Is there a way to create an alias for each one of these mapAction that my page can differentiate?
Or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `namespacing` if you are using modules in composing your store.

Something like this:

```
 const moduleA = {
  namespaced: true, //namespacing set to true.
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}

const moduleB = {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    namespacedModuleA: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  }
})
```

Then in your `mapAction` you can do this :

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
        actionOfA: ['nameSpacedModuleA/actionOfA'],
        actionOfB: ['actionOfB'],
    }),
}
```

If you do not want to use `mapActions`, you can also do

```
this.$store.dispatch('nameSpacedModuleA/actionOfA')
```

More on `namespacing` with modules [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is a way ! Here you are :

```js
methods: {
    ...mapActions('documents', { setDocumentImage: 'setDocumentImage' }),
    ...mapActions('documentAddress', { setDocumentAddressImage: 'setDocumentImage' }),
    ...mapActions('selfie', { setSelfieDocumentImage: 'setDocumentImage' }),
}
```